# How do I call a method with an ActionEvent parameter on another method

Tags: java, methods, javafx, scenebuilder, actionevent

I'm trying to fill a queue for an application that creates a Tennis Tournament

[image]

When I click the button "Crear Torneo" (as seen in the image), I'm creating the queue in the method "crearTorneo". When I hit the "Añadir" button (also seen in the image), it takes the information in the several TextFields and creates an object in the "llenarCola" method, which is returned with the intention of filling the queue.

Now, here is my llenarCola method:

```
@FXML
private NodoJugadores llenarCola(ActionEvent event) 
{
    int cedula = Integer.parseInt(textCedula.getText());
    int edad = Integer.parseInt(textEdad.getText());
    NodoJugadores jugador = new NodoJugadores(textNombre.getText(), cedula, textSexo.getText(), edad, textEquipo.getText(), 0);

    return jugador;
}
```

and here is my crearTorneo method:

```
@FXML
private void crearTorneo(ActionEvent event)
{
    NodoJugadores jugador;
    ColaJugadores cola = new ColaJugadores(); 

    jugador = llenarCola();
```

Clearly, when I call the method llenarCola inside crearTorneo, I'm missing the ActionEvent parameter, which brings me to my question: How do I call a method with an ActionEvent parameter on another method? Or maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way?

It's the first time I use JavaFX, so maybe there's another way (a good practice way) that I don't know of. I still need the method llenarCola to be called ONLY when the button "Añadir" is pressed. I'm using Scene Builder 2 and Netbeans 8.0.2.

Comment: If you're not using the `event` instance inside the method, you can call the method and pass in `null`. Or you can instantiate an `ActionEvent`. Or you can have your `ActionEvent` method delegate to another method that doesn't have a parameter.

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129568/elegant-way-to-handle-keyboard-input-in-javafx

Comment: But I still need the llenarCola method to be called only when the button "Añadir" is pressed. If I put a null parameter, wouldn't it behave differently? Also, I don't find the other question all that relevant.

Comment: If you don't reference the event in your metod, you will not notice the difference just call crearTornero(null)

Answer (score 1):

This is basically identical to [Elegant way to handle Keyboard Input in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129568/elegant-way-to-handle-keyboard-input-in-javafx)

You can do

```
@FXML
private void llenarCola(ActionEvent event) {
    llenarCola() ;
}

private NodoJugadores llenarCola() {
    int cedula = Integer.parseInt(textCedula.getText());
    int edad = Integer.parseInt(textEdad.getText());
    NodoJugadores jugador = new NodoJugadores(textNombre.getText(), cedula, textSexo.getText(), edad, textEquipo.getText(), 0);

    return jugador;
}
```

and then you can invoke the no-arg version:

```
@FXML
private void crearTorneo(ActionEvent event){
    NodoJugadores jugador;
    ColaJugadores cola = new ColaJugadores(); 

    jugador = llenarCola();

    // ...
}
```

Comment: thank you so much :) I see your answers on many javafx posts